# Python3 abstractmethod, parameters differ from overridden method

Tags: python, methods, pylint, abc

The class Parent has an abstract method and I need to use a different number and types of arguments in the method in the children classes/methods.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Parent(ABC):
    """Parent"""
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self, *args):
        """method"""


class Child1(Parent):
    """Child1"""
    def method(self, arg1: int):
        print(arg1)


class Child2(Parent):
    """Child2"""
    def method(self, arg1: str, arg2: dict):
        print(arg1, arg2)
```

For this code pylint is showing me next warning:

> [W0221(arguments-differ), Child1.method] Parameters differ from
> overridden 'method' method

Is it possible to solve the pylint warning and continue using different arguments in children classes?
I don't want to use `*args` in children methods.

Comment: If the methods take different arguments you're breaking Liskov Substitution Principle. Pylint is correctly marking your method as bad style.

Comment: A caller that's trying to use the `Parent` interface you've defined will find that it doesn't actually work in either `Child` implementation.  This is not simply bad code, it is malicious code.  Linters exist specifically to help people not write code like this -- if you want to write intentionally evil code, you don't want to be using a linter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this pattern is incorrect and incompatible with pylint.

Comment: @Samwise What's the alternative then? Should you *never* use abstractmethods if you have child classes with different types of input? Such a parent class seems like a good place to define commonalities of your classes.

Comment: The point of an abstract parent class is to define a common interface that you can use without knowing anything about the concrete implementation.  This is the exact opposite of that -- there is no common interface, and you absolutely have to know which implementation you have in order to use the class correctly.  There is no reason for `Parent` to exist in this scenario other than attempting to confuse someone who's trying to figure out the code.

Comment: To put it another way: *what commonalities*?